# Filter Data by date range c# mvc4

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

First Table  Card : `CardId, Description`. - Keeps record of all the card available Second Table RegistartionDt : `RegistartionDtId, RegisteredDateTime , CardId`. keep data of the time and data a particular card is used.

I want to make a search function that will search for the cards by the date . For example the user will chose from the drop-down menu the date. Start date and end date and search for the cards being used in that range.

I have this so far :

```
public ActionResult List ()
{
    CardDBEntities _db = new CardDBEntities();

    var cards = (from c in _db.Cards
                 join d in _db.RegistrationDTs 
                 on c.CardId equals d.CardId
                 where d.RegistrationDateTime >= startDate && 
                       d.RegistrationDateTime <= endDate
                 select new
                 {
                     d.CardId,
                     c.Description
                 }).OrderByAscending(x => x.RegistrationDateTime)
                   .ToList();;

    return View(cards);
}
```

What should I do in the view? How to show my result? How should the endDate and startDate be defined I did not define them anywhere. I want the enddate and the startdate be the value that the users will insert in the searchbox.

Pls help.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
// Declare a model class in your models folder, like below
// You could give any name you want to this class
public class ModelName
{
    public int CardId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegistrationDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Then inside your controller, you could refactor your method to the following one:

```
public ActionResult List (DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    using(var db = new CardDBEntities())
    {
        var cards = (from c in db.Cards
                     join d in db.RegistrationDTs 
                     on c.CardId equals d.CardId
                     where d.RegistrationDateTime >= startDate && 
                           d.RegistrationDateTime <= endDate
                    select new ModelName
                    {
                        CardId = d.CardId,
                        Description = c.Description,
                        RegistrationDateTime = d.RegistrationDateTime
                    }).OrderByAscending(x => x.RegistrationDateTime)
                      .ToList();

        ViewData["cards"] = cards;

        return View();  
    }
}
```

> How should the endDate and startDate be defined I did not define them
>   anywhere.

You could define them as parameters in your `ActionResult` method.

> What should I do in the view?

You can read the data from the `ViewBag` collection.

> What should I do in the view?

That depends solely on how you wan to present your result.

Comment: I find this more logical. Thank you so much.Let me try it.

Comment: Do you have anyidea why I get :
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'startDate' of non-nullable type 'System.DateTime' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult List(System.DateTime, System.DateTime)' in 'Reader1.Controllers.CardController'

Comment: @BesaNeziri unfortunately I have no idea why you got this error.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. I really appreciate it

Comment: @BesaNeziri you welcome dude ! Not a problem at all.